# Internationalization of Django Library

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm using a library (or python package? Not very familiar with the vernacular) that has all the good {% trans %} to translate strings.

Whenever I generate the strings from my app with the makemessages command, those strings are never listed, I have to add them manually one by one.

What Am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide some code which doesn't work?

Comment: I ... can't? 
I use a library, i could show you the code of this, but this would consist of a html template like this :
{% load i18n %}
[...]
{% trans "Choose your option" %}

Whenever I do a manage.py makemessages, this string never shows in my app, but the library is put in INSTALLED_APPS.
My question being, is it normal, are the package supposed to ship with embedded translations?

Comment: You could provide your settings for i18n and so on. It's hard to predict what you are missing or doing wrong. If string appears in *.po file, add translation and use `compilemessages` after. Honestly, I didn't get what package and embedded translations do you mean.